# Excel VBA script filters header unexpectedly

Tags: vba, excel

**Introduction**

I have some spreadsheets like the following.

[image: original data after script execution]

Here the header is on rows 16 and 17. There is a "header" to the left (not shown) among the earlier rows and columns that includes a picture, some non-tabular data, a legend, etc., that is unimportant here. Header text on row 16 is obfuscated because *reasons*. Data marked in bold red indicates that that sample point has undergone some process. Here is the code snippet from the script that highlights those data points in bold red.

```
' Traverse columns applying redding until hitting the row end, Comment, or SpGr: whichever comes first
For currIndex = abcDateCol + 1 To lastCol
  ' Check for exit conditions:
  If Cells(abcDateRowDesc, currIndex).Value() = "Comments" Then Exit For

  If Cells(abcDateRowDesc, currIndex).Value() <> "" Then
    If Cells(abcDateRowDesc, currIndex + 1).Value() = "process" Then
      ' Looks like we have a column of something Red-able
      Columns(ColumnLetter(currIndex) & ":" & ColumnLetter(currIndex + 1)).Select
      Selection.AutoFilter ' Turn on autofiltering (hopefully)
      Selection.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=1", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=e"
      Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 3
      Selection.Font.Bold = True
      Selection.AutoFilter ' Turn off autofiltering
      Columns(ColumnLetter(currIndex + 1) & ":" & ColumnLetter(currIndex + 1)).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If
  End If
Next currIndex
```

**Context**

Here, `abcDateCol` refers to column AE, `lastCol` refers to column AQ, `abcDateRow` (not shown, but available) and `abcDateRowDesc` refer to the header rows 16 and 17 respectively, and the `ColumnLetter` function is a user-defined function that returns the human-readable column letter(s) given a column number; this is common functionality you may have seen elsewhere, or even made yourself.

**Let's Continue**

Never mind that the condition in `If Cells(abcDateRowDesc, currIndex).Value() = "Comments"` is never satisfied because of an oversight (I'm assuming) -- two different rows, guaranteed.

Let's take a look at what the spreadsheet looks like before this script is executed.

[image: original data before script execution]

So, the script takes pairs of columns, and for each pair of columns it marks data cells bold red if a data cell's right-adjacent cell has a 1 (or an "e"?) (as a boolean; answers the question, "Has this sample point undergone whatever process?") and then trashes the "process" column.

**The Problem**

A client wants the gratuitous header gone, so they may more easily import the spreadsheet into whatever solution they have. Delete rows 1 through 15, and this is what I get.

[image]

What in the bleepity-bleep happened to the header? I don't understand how this first row gets highlighted. It seems too perfectly weird. Now, let's revisit the very first spreadsheet.

[image]

I've filled the "header" with some dummy text after the script executed. Wow, there's the first row reddened again, this time *ad infinitum*! So, this problem has always existed. Oh, and the first column, too! And, it magically stops right above the proper header so we would never see it.

**The Questions**

Why is this script unexpectedly reddening the first row and column? Can this be easily solved, or am I looking at some sort of a rewrite? If so, please point me in the general direction.

It helps to mention that these spreadsheets are generated from a Windows application and their scripts executed before a user has a copy of their spreadsheet. Also, regarding the second picture (the spreadsheet with the "process" columns shown), this spreadsheet is not something that normally exists. I generated it for the sake of this post by skipping the script's `for` loop. The application uses a chosen spreadsheet template, that looks the same minus the data, fills in the sample data, and then executes several scripts over the data.

I considered using conditional formatting, but there are a few dozen spreadsheet templates. Even if I just change the one I need, I can't change the fact that these common scripts run over it. I feel my best option is to correct the script. And, I wouldn't change the script to account for my edge case. The whole ecosystem feels flaky, but that's just subjective.

**Note**

I am not the author of this script (or any of my company's VBA!). I'm considering this an inheritance tax levied upon me.

***Update**

I was asked if I traced through this code. I apologize that I didn't include that information in my original post. Here is what I know. `Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 3` turns the cells in the selection that satisfy the autofilter plus the first row (two cells as only two columns are selected at a given time), and `Selection.Font.Bold = True` makes the same cells bold in the same manner. I suspect it has something to do with the autofilter, so I'm going to take a look at the answers now.

Comment: (a) Have you tried stepping through the code one line at a time to determine which line of code is causing those cells to be changed to red?  (b) Have you checked that the cells that turned red didn't turn red due to conditional formatting?  e.g. if there was a conditional format in cell AG16 that set the cell to red if `=0=IFERROR(IF(AG15="XYZ",0,1),0)` then it would become red when the cell moved from AG16 to AG1.  (I'm just making that test up, solely to highlight that shifting cells could cause the conditional format to fire.)

Comment: I'll answer **b** first. None of the templates' sheets have any conditional formatting rules. I'm glad you mentioned that as I hadn't checked prior. As for **a**, I'm trying to do my part before I ask the community for help. Yes, I have traced, I'll edit my post to include that information so I don't have a ludicrously long comment. Gotta run, so I'll edit from home or tomorrow morning. Thanks again.

Comment: Just before I log out, I see there is an answer. I'll dig into it tomorrow, but given my tracing, I suspected it had something to do with autofilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a (commented) refactoring of your code that should do:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim abcDateCol As Long, lastCol As Long, abcDateRow As Long, abcDateRowDesc As Long, currIndex As Long

    abcDateCol = 31
    lastCol = 43
    abcDateRow = 16 '<--| you can change it to 1 for the last "scenario"
    abcDateRowDesc = 17 '<--| you can change it to 2 for the last "scenario"


    For currIndex = abcDateCol + 1 To lastCol '<--| loop through columns
        With Cells(abcDateRow, currIndex) '<--| refer to cell in current column on row abcDateRow
            If .Value = "Comments" Then Exit For '<--| Check for exit conditions on row 'abcDateRow'

            If .Offset(1).Value <> "" And .Offset(1, 1).Value = "process" Then '<--| Check for processing conditions on row 'abcDateRowDesc'
                With .Resize(.Offset(, 1).End(xlDown).Row - .Row + 1, 2) '<-- consider the range from current referenced cell 1 column to the right and down to last 'process' number/letter
                    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=1", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=e" '<--| filter on "process" field with "1" or "e"
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any values match...
                        With .Offset(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 2, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font '<--|... consider only filtered values skipping headers (2 rows), and apply formatting
                            .ColorIndex = 3
                            .Bold = True
                        End With
                    End If
                    .AutoFilter '<-- reset autofilter
                    .Resize(, 1).Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft '<-- delete the "2nd" column (i.e. one column offsetted to the right)
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next currIndex
End Sub
```

there were two faults in your "inherited" code:

- `If Cells(abcDateRowDesc, currIndex).Value() = "Comments" Then Exit For` was to be referred to `abcDateRow` index row instead
- the formatting would be applied to all cells, were they filtered (matching) or not

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner. This solution worked for my case, and I tested it across all my other spreadsheets with success. I'm still mentally chewing on some of your solution's details. Your first bullet point I was aware of (I mentioned it in my **Let's Continue** section). This autofilter thing feels too weird for my tastes.

Comment: Yes, weird but quite useful. Glad to see it helped. Good coding!

Answer (score 3):

This edit should fix your problems, hopefully (they did for my remake of your spreadsheet, but we won't know til you try on the real thing)

```
' Traverse columns applying redding until hitting the row end, Comment, or SpGr: whichever comes first
For currIndex = abcDateCol + 1 To lastCol
    ' Check for exit conditions:
    If Cells(abcDateRowDesc, currIndex).Value() = "Comments" Then Exit For

    If Cells(abcDateRowDesc, currIndex).Value() <> "" Then
        If Cells(abcDateRowDesc, currIndex + 1).Value() = "process" Then
            ' Looks like we have a column of something Red-able
            'Columns(ColumnLetter(currIndex) & ":" & ColumnLetter(currIndex + 1)).Select
            With Range(Cells(abcDateRowDesc, currIndex), Cells(abcDateRowDesc, currIndex + 1).End(xlDown))
                .AutoFilter 2, "=1", xlOr, "=e"
                ' Don't format header
                With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)                         .Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    .Font.Bold = True
                    .AutoFilter ' Turn off autofiltering
                End With
            End With
            Columns(currIndex + 1).Delete xlShiftLeft
        End If
    End If
Next currIndex
```

This all starts with a quirk of how the code is choosing its range to autofilter. The selected area is the full column, instead of the area you actually want to format (row 18 to the last entry). It seems that autofiltering on a full column with empty top rows automatically sets the first nonempty row as the header row. So the header is left unfiltered/unhidden by the statement, and it gets colored in as part of the full column selection. So that's why your headers are getting colored.

Now, if you tried to test this by putting data in the above empty rows like "a", those values would become the first ones in the column and would be selected as the headers - meaning *those* values get colored. *Whatever is in the first nonempty row of your columns will be the autofilter header and will get colored.*

But that should only affect the columns you explicitly colored, not the entirety of the first row, right? The problem here is that Excel likes to make assumptions about data in order to save time. So if you have a whole row full of red, bold **"a"**'s and right next to them you put in another "a" to test whether that cell is formatted or not... well, it automatically gives you a red, bold **"a"** despite the cell being previously unformatted! And if you keep going down the row in this way, it'll appear like your whole row got formatted. But, if you were to jump over a few columns (say, 5-ish) and enter in another "a", voila, it's unformatted, and any "a"s you put in near it will be too. You can also check what Excel by deleting an unformatted "a" in a far off column, then continuing to enter **"a"**'s all the way down until you reach that same cell - *this time, the **"a"** will be red and bold because all of the others in the row were, too, even though we just checked that this was an unformatted cell!*

Basically, having the wrong range for your autofilter made things act very unexpectedly, then trying to test the formatting issue by entering in values just made everything less clear. The code I've provided just autofilters the relevant area (row 17 to the last contiguous row), fixing the core issue.

Comment: ++ for the detailed answer. Great effort.

Comment: This solution did not work in my case. Hilariously, it red-highlighed the second row, the row of _per mille_ signs. I couldn't even work out a solution by altering some of it. However, I did like the tidier code, and the removal of the unnecessary use of `ColumnLetter`. It also helped me better understand my problem. SO points for you.

Comment: @jefff That's because the the second row was part of the With Object - I expected it to be colored. Code is now edited to take account of this and remove it from the formatting.